# foreach loop and getting value of the loop in codeigniter, php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I have a foreach loop that loops to get the value of filename, alt and caption.

Controller

```
public function save_product(){
        log_message('debug', '['.__CLASS__.']['.__FUNCTION__.'][start]');
        $this->load->helper('form');

            //Grab all elements of the form with a name attribute
            $post = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);

            //$key refer to the $this->input->post('item_id');
            //$value refer to the value of the post key

            foreach($post as $key=> $value)
            {
                //retrieve the $key that start with 'images_files'
                if (0 === strpos($key, 'images_files'))
                {
                    log_message('debug', '['.__CLASS__.']['.__FUNCTION__.']['.$key.']['.print_r($value,TRUE).']');
                    var_dump($value);
                    echo "</br>";
                }
                elseif(0 === strpos($key, 'images_alt'))
                {
                    log_message('debug', '['.__CLASS__.']['.__FUNCTION__.']['.$key.']['.print_r($value,TRUE).']');
                    var_dump($value);
                    echo "</br>";
                }
                elseif(0 === strpos($key, 'images_caption'))
                {
                    log_message('debug', '['.__CLASS__.']['.__FUNCTION__.']['.$key.']['.print_r($value,TRUE).']');
                    var_dump($value);
                    echo "</br>";
                    /*array_push($images, 
                        array(
                            ,,$value)
                    );*/
                }
            }
            //var_dump($images);

            $item_id = $this->input->post('item_id');
            $category_id = $this->input->post('category_id');
            $item_info = $this->input->post('information');
            $oldcolor_id = $this->input->post('oldcolor_id');
            $color_id = $this->input->post('color_id');
            if ($color_id == "")
            {
                $color_id = $oldcolor_id;
            }
            else
            {
                $color_id = $color_id;
            }
            $isClearance = $this->input->post('isClearance');
            $parent_item_id = $this->input->post('parent_item_id');
            $model_no = $this->input->post('model_no');
            $volume = $this->input->post('volume');
            $short_desc = $this->input->post('short');
            $long_desc = $this->input->post('long');
            $release_from = $this->input->post('from');
            $release_to = $this->input->post('to');

            $this->load->model('backend_product_model');
            $this->backend_product_model->product_update($item_id, $category_id, $item_info, $color_id, $isClearance, $parent_item_id, $model_no, $volume, $short_desc, $long_desc, $release_from, $release_to);
    }
```

Output

```
array(1) { ["4548736020191"]=> array(1) { ["filename"]=> string(36) "875fb89e3d00a78e177a0ad4ab0c2fde.jpg" } } 
array(1) { ["4548736020191"]=> array(1) { ["alt"]=> string(5) "alt 1" } } 
array(1) { ["4548736020191"]=> array(1) { ["caption"]=> string(9) "caption 1" } }
```

How can I go about getting only the "875fb89e3d00a78e177a0ad4ab0c2fde.jpg", "alt 1" and "caption 1" so as to pass together with other "post" information to the product_update() function?

Comment: Take a look at the array push function

Comment: Are 'images_files', 'images_alt' and  'images_caption' the full names for fields?

Comment: Show the code for `backend_product_model->product_update()`